# streaming desktop to flash player

Tags: java, video-streaming, flash

I would like to stream my desktop screen (or just one application), via Flash player, to the internet.

I have wowze media player to multicast it but I have to create a stream to give to wowze.

Does anybody have have any idea how to start what would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

http://1.pe-web.ro/dev/flashPlatform/flashBuilder/flexJavaApplet/flexPrintScreen/
You could start from here. This is an app that uses Java to capture the screen and sends the picture to flash

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a [RED5](http://osflash.org/red5) server and TightVNC with a customized version of the Java client that will publish frames as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

[Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/) is a cross-platform (Windows and Mac) option. Captures the screen, plus audio. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any "out of the box" software use the Flash Player to encode your screen and stream it to Wowza. I do believe that it must be developed from scratch.

But I've been using for a while a Java based desktop encoder that streams to Wowza media server. It is part of the Red5 ecosystem: [red5-screenshare](http://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/)

Answer (score -1):

If what you mean by create stream is to have a virtual camera that captures your desktop screen in a way you can select in your multicatser app then you should check out ScreenCamera. It does exactly that and you can select the frame-rate you want. You can find ScreenCamera here:
http://www.pcwinsoft.com/screencamera/download.asp
http://www.pcwinsoft.com/screencamera/

Hope this helps,
Alex